# Ansible run_once selects an unreachble host

Tags: ansible

"If you want a task to run only on the first host in your batch of hosts, set run_once to true on that task"

According to Ansible documentation, run_once selects the first host in the host-group. Is it always guaranteed the host picked is available ?

Link: [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once)

Comment: If you previously gathered facts (or ran any other task that detected the host was unreachable): Yes, as unreachable hosts will be out of the host batch loop.

Comment: Well in my case, the very first task has run_once and it picks the first host from the host-group and it is unreachable.

Comment: Then put an other task before that which will test reachability or your hosts. gathering facts is a perfect one for your use cas IMO. Crafting an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ansible detects a host is unreachable, it will take it out of the host batch loop. Here is a very simple example you can run and play around with. I use the "natural" fact gathering to detect unreachable host and the first task will `run_once` on the first available host in the list.

My test `inventories/default/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    i.dont.exist:
    fakebut.existing.host:
      ansible_connection: local
    fake2but.existing.host:
      ansible_connection: local
```

You can play around and comment out the local connections to make the hosts unreachable.

My demo `playbooks/test_unreachable.yml`:

```yaml
---
---
- hosts: all
  # Make sure we gather facts so there is a first connection
  # attempt on all hosts. Note: written for clarity.
  # It is normally the default and you can ommit
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: a task that should run once on a reachable host
      debug:
        msg: "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      run_once: true

    - name: just a confirmation we only run on reachable hosts
      debug:
        msg: "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbooks/test_unreachable.yml 

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [i.dont.exist]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname i.dont.exist: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
ok: [fake2but.existing.host]
ok: [fakebut.existing.host]

TASK [a task that should run once on a reachable host] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [fakebut.existing.host] => {
    "msg": "I'm running on fakebut.existing.host"
}

TASK [just a confirmation we only run on reachable hosts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [fakebut.existing.host] => {
    "msg": "I'm running on fakebut.existing.host"
}
ok: [fake2but.existing.host] => {
    "msg": "I'm running on fake2but.existing.host"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fake2but.existing.host     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
fakebut.existing.host      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
i.dont.exist               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can make more or less hosts available in the inventory. The `run_once` task will always run on an available host (provided there is at least one)